# Agregar texto a un div sin eliminar la etiqueta span que se encuentra dentro

Tags: javascript

Cómo puedo añadir texto al div sin que elimine la etiqueta span, he intentado de dos formas y no logro añadir el texto sin que se borre el span.

```js
let message = document.querySelector(".message");

// REMUEVE LA ETIQUETA SPAN
//message.innerText = "Continuar";

// AÑADE EL TEXTO DESPUES DEL SPAN
//message.innerText += "Continuar";
```

```html
<div class="message">Cambiar texto<span>-></span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Analizando el elemento con la clase **message** veo que está compuesto de dos nodos hijos:

```
childNodes: [object NodeList] {
  0: [object Text] { ... },
  1: [object HTMLSpanElement] { ... },
```

por lo tanto, si apuntamos al primero de ellos mediante la propiedad de lectura [childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) y su número de índice (el **0** en este caso), combinada con la propiedad [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) entonces el segundo (el span) queda inalterable.

Ejemplo:

```js
let message = document.querySelector(".message");
message.childNodes[0].textContent = "Continuar"
```

```html
<div class="message">Cambiar texto<span>-></span></div>
```

### Otra solución a este caso específico

Volviendo a analizar el elemento, veo que también, en este caso, podemos utilizar la propiedad firstChild, pues en su estructura aparece esto:

```
      firstChild: [circular object Text],
      firstElementChild: [circular object HTMLSpanElement] :
```

por lo tanto, también así funcionaría:

```js
let message = document.querySelector(".message");
message.firstChild.textContent = "Continuar"
```

```html
<div class="message">Cambiar texto<span>-></span></div>
```

Comment: Muy interesante solución como siempre masterguru

Comment: @LuisS.Romero jeje, bueno, ha sido suerte :-)  He puesto un console.log(message) para que me escupiera todo el objeto (2374 líneas) y luego he buscado **span** por ahí y lo he encontrado de ese modo y pam, se me encendió la bombilla :-)  Un placer verte activo, saludos!

Comment: Tremendoooo jajaja (2374 líneas explotó mi cabeza). Ha sido un placer también volver a cruzar letras, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar la propiedad innerHTML en lugar de innerText, y así conservar el span

```js
message.innerHTML = "Continuar<span>-></span>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Una opción que además te daría independencia del texto frente al segundo span es usar 2 span que son elementos inline, esto te permitiría usar diferentes etiquetas, diferentes formatos, de forma muy sencilla.

**Quedando en HTML:**

```
<div><span class="message">Cambiar texto</span><span>-></span></div>
```

**Quedando en JS:**

```
let message = document.querySelector(".message");
message.textContent = "hola";
```

El problema es que innerText o innerHTML sobreescriben el contenido del div padre que es el elemento capturado.

---

**Notas de laboratorio:**

```
// REMUEVE LA ETIQUETA SPAN
//message.innerText = "Continuar";
```

Esto reemplaza todo el contenido del div, por lo que desaparece el `<span>`.

```
// AÑADE EL TEXTO DESPUES DEL SPAN
//message.innerText += "Continuar";
```

Esto es el contenido que tiene o sea el texto + span + "Continuar", ya que **a += b** en este caso actúa igual que **a = a + b**

Ten presente que al usar una clase en el querySelector solo te traerá el primer elemento con esa clase, si se desea que afecte a varios elementos deberás usar querySelectorAll, lo que devuelve un array que posteriormente podrás recorrer y hacer lo que desees con cada elemento en cada iteración.

En caso de que el objetivo sea seleccionar un único elemento, una alternativa podría ser seleccionar por id usando querySelector("#id") o getElementById("id").